# Find next Numbered Bullet Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word, vsto

Suppose we have the following list.

1. item1
2. List item
3. List item
4. List item
5. List item

I have the range of bullet 3 and I want to find its next bullet using C#.
Need help regarding this.

```
private Range ListParaRangeNext(Range range)
    {

        Range forparas = range.Duplicate;
        ListParagraphs paras = null;
        if (range.ListFormat.List != null)
        {

            paras = range.ListFormat.List.ListParagraphs;
            //MessageBox.Show(paras.Count.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            forparas.SetRange(range.Start, range.StoryLength - 1);
            paras = forparas.ListParagraphs;
        }
        List<Paragraph> ienum = paras.Cast<Paragraph>().ToList();


        //ienum = (from para in ienum
        //         where para.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber == range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber
        //            && para.Range.End > range.Start
        //         select para).ToList();



        List<Paragraph> temp = new List<Paragraph>();
        for (int i = 0, length = ienum.Count; i < length; ++i)
        {
            if (ienum[i].Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber == range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber && ienum[i].Range.End > range.Start)
                temp.Add(ienum[i]);
        }
        ienum = temp;
        ienum = ienum.OrderBy(o => o.Range.Start).ToList();

        if (ienum.Count > 1)
        {
            Range current = ienum[1].Range;
            if (current.ListFormat.ListValue - 1 == range.ListFormat.ListValue)
            {
                return current;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am using this function to find but it is taking most of the time of my program.
any optimizations suggested?

Comment: I'm sorry, What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is a collection of paragraphs / ranges

To jump to the next bullet item you use
`Range.Next Unit:=wdParagraph`

That is ok for "**linear lists**" but is the list is strew with "**ordinary**" paragraphs, you will need to check the `ListFormat` property that will help you determine whether it is list item or not

**[EDIT]**

Here is a sample code to get the range object

```
In VSTO

Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
Range new_rng = rng.Next(WdUnits.wdParagraph);

In VBA

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection.Range
Dim new_rng As Range
Set new_rng = rng.Next wdParagraph
```

I didn't test but it should work

Comment: I don't want to jump to the next bullet item. I just want to find out the next item.

Comment: I just edited the code. The ``Range.Next`` method return another ``range`` object

Comment: Thanks a lot your solution almost solved my problem but is there any way to check that the List is alphabetical or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of strings- find some member and get index of it. and next item will be index incremented by 1.

```
var index = lists.IndexOf(lists.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "222"));
 var next = lists[index + 1];
```